# S3 Obfuscated const_missing_from_s3_library error

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I'm using the typical Mac/Ruby 1.9.3p125

```
irb>

require 'aws/s3'
AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(:access_key_id => 'AccessKey',:secret_access_key => 'SecretKey' )
Service.buckets
```

(Same error with Bucket.find or almost anything!)

Gives me:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Service
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:206
 :in `const_missing_from_s3_library'
from (irb):23
from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

I'm following documentation almost to spec but I'm so confused as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either include AWS::S3 in your class or do AWS::S3.Service.

Here's some code samples:

```
require 'aws/s3'
class MyClass
  include AWS::S3
  AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(:access_key_id => 'AccessKey',:secret_access_key => 'SecretKey' )
  Service.buckets
end
```

or

```
require 'aws/s3'
class MyClass
  AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(:access_key_id => 'AccessKey',:secret_access_key => 'SecretKey' )
  AWS::S3::Service.buckets
end
```

Comment: can you be a bit more specific for rails newbies?

Comment: Hi Chris, I added a couple of code samples. I haven't worked with this code in quite a while, so let me know if that helps you.